# Use number of children in css calc()

Tags: html, css

How can I make an element as wide as the number of it's children multiplies by 10px? Using HTML and CSS only, no JavaScript.

```css
svg {
  max-width: calc(number-of-g-children * 10px);
}
```

```html
<svg>
<g></g>
<g></g>
</svg>
```

in this example the SVG should be at most 20 pixels wide

Comment: This is not possible with *only* HTML & CSS.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? It seems you are asking for a solution to a problem you think may solve your _underlying_ problem.

Answer (score 1):

It would require a lot of CSS to capture all possible widths. However, if you're in a position to use SASS/LESS/SCSS, you can generate the required CSS up to a specified maximum width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

svg:has(g:nth-child(1)) {
  width: 10px;
}

svg:has(g:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 20px;
}

svg:has(g:nth-child(3)) {
  width: 30px;
}

svg:has(g:nth-child(4)) {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<g></g>
<g></g>
</svg>

<svg>
<g></g>
<g></g>
<g></g>
</svg>

<svg>
<g></g>
<g></g>
<g></g>
<g></g>
</svg>
```